# Current TabPanel ID in onClientLoad CSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have client sided code in the onClientLoad event of my form that governs field hiding. Problem is, it depends on values in the first tabPanel. If I switch to the second tabPanel, it stops working. I can no longer switch back to any other tabPanel.

How can I within the onClientLoad event using CSJS identify which panel I currently am on?

Comment: I'd rather use the dojo tabs. Less headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a tab panel whenever you switch between tabs the fields are recalculated.

So, I would rather suggest you to put a visibility formula on field instead.

Comment: Yeah, as a result of another question I've had to do a little rethinking. Yes, I prefer to do client-sided hiding when the user changes values on the form, but the onClientLoad event's not the right place to do field hiding. I've added styleClass computations to the fields and it appears to be behaving now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all tab panels have a nice id. Then in your script block you can add something like:

```
  var t1 = dojo.byId("#{id:tab1}");
  if (t1) { // do your stuff }
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: dojo.byId("#{id:PreparerPanel}") returns the same thing as XSP.getElementById("#{id:PreparerPanel}"); a DispHTMLAnchorElement. When they are executed for each panel, the values for them are returned regardless of whether you happen to be presently in the tab.

Comment: Though my need for this has diminished, it'd still be of interest to know what panel I'm on in CSJS. Thanks for *ALL* your help stwissel! I really appreciate your generosity with your time and answers.